# Internet Connection Error with updating Ubuntu

Tags: updates, internet, update-manager, connection

Failed to download repository information, "check your Internet connection"  After using this on wifi and then directly plugging the laptop into wire-cable for faster, guaranteed Internet, nothing is wrong with my connection. I would like to upgrade my ubuntu. It possible I might have some odd malware or spyware. Can someone write down a step by step process to update Ubuntu properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you know your internet connection is working, then it may be the repository is not reachable or offline.  You can change this from the Software Center or Synaptic.  [More information is available here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_Software_Tab).

[image]

You could first try changing the entry in the list "Download From".  After changing, you will need to update the software available, as the instructions will say (reload).

If that doesn't help, you may want to edit your question and put more information about the error's text and how it comes up.